# Make each table row scrollable in android programatically

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, tablerow

i have a table row that works fine now in want each one the rows be horizontally scrollable in code.
It's my code,when i add my contents to horizontal scroll view it force stops:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <counter; i++) {
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
        final TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        HorizontalScrollView hsw = null;

        final TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));


        t.setText("   "+filenames[i]+"");
        t.setWidth(20);
        t.setHeight(65);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT);
        t.setTextSize(15);
        t.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                  new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                  (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



                row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);


        row.addView(t);
        hsw.addView(row);


        table.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?what did i do wrong?
Tanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your HorizontalScrollView null?
Adding the stack trace would be helpful too.